# Eclipse/Checkstyle - Force class/global variables to be private

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

Is there any way to configure Eclipse or Checkstyle to convert or mark as waring/error if any class/global variable isn't defined as private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using the following regex **(public)(\s)([a-zA-Z0-9]*?)(\s)([a-zA-Z0-9]*?);** in Checkstyle